# Cannot shorten capsize errorbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have this code in Matlab R2015a:

```
figure
set(gcf,'color','w')
hax = axes;
errorbar(f_cc/(1e6), abs(Z_cc),err_Z,'o-');
hax.XScale = 'log';
grid on
xlim([3.6846 3.6900])
xlabel('f(MHz)')
ylabel('|Z(f)|')
```

where `f_cc`, `Z_cc` and `err_Z` are vector with 31 components and double precision (Z is in addition complex). However, I get this result:

[image: plot showing error bars with caps that span the whole plot]

I thought the problem could be the 'capsize' of the errorbars, but when I try to add the attribute 'capsize':

```
errorbar(f_cc/(1e6), abs(Z_cc),err_Z,'o-','Capsize',1);`
```

then Matlab gives me an error:

> There is no Capsize property on the ErrorBar class

so I don't known how to change it (if that's the problem).

Comment: You have R2015a. MathWorks introduced that functionality in R2016b. See the fifth point under 'Graphics' in the release notes here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2016b&endrelease=R2016b&category=graphics&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=

Comment: [This submission](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22826-adjust-error-bar-width) on File-Exchange may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The oldest version of MATLAB I have is R2016a, and I could reproduce your error bar bug with it. In R2017a it has been fixed.

The problem arises with the combination of `errorbar` and the logarithmic x-axis with a (relatively) small spread. The error bars work perfectly fine if you keep the x-axis linear, or if the x-values have a wider spread. For example:

```matlab
x = linspace(3.6846, 3.6900, 20);
y = rand(size(x));
e = linspace(0.01, 0.5, numel(x));
errorbar(x, y, e, 'o-')
set(gca, 'XScale','log')
xlim(x([1,end]))
```

Shows the ridiculous error bars, but if we set `x = linspace(3.6846, 3.6900*10, 20);` (i.e. having the x-axis span a decade) the plot looks perfectly fine.

#### Workaround #1

Since the data has such a small spread, there is no point in using a logarithmic axis. With `set(gca, 'XScale','lin')` your plot will look almost the same, but with normal error bars.

#### Workaround #2

Use a linear x-axis, but simulate logarithmic plotting:

```matlab
errorbar(log(x), y, e, 'o-')
ticks = 3.684:0.002:3.690;
set(gca, 'XTick',log(ticks), 'XTickLabel',ticks);
xlim(log(x([1,end])))
```

But honestly, this doesn't even look like logarithmic axis because the range is so small, I can't really tell the difference... :)

---

Regarding the error setting the `'capsize'` property: As [Sardar Usama mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55983815/cannot-shorten-capsize-errorbar-matlab/55988897#comment98617111_55983815), this property was introduced in R2016b, so it is expected that you would get that error message.

Comment: I think none of your solutions works, because there are noticeable differences between logarithmic plot and linear plot

Comment: @Josemi: Workaround #2 creates a logarithmic plot. What differences do you see? Are you missing the minor tick marks at logarithmic intervals?

Comment: I think it's because the y-axis doesn't appear to be logarithmic

Comment: @Josemi: You can still make the y-axis logarithmic if you want. The bug relates to the x-axis only. Your code and example plot in the question don't have logarithmic y-axis either.